# Should I mention that I was an athlete in a curriculum for a PhD application?

Tags: phd, advisor

I am going to apply for a PhD in mathematics in north Europe. During my high school and undergraduate years, I was also a semi-professional athlete, and I retired when I was a graduate student to focus on my studies. I think being an athlete at a high level tells many things about a PhD student. A high level former athlete has probably developed a strong attitude for work, knows how to focus and how to manage their time; moreover, high level sport teaches you also how to manage stress and failures. However, I am afraid that a potential PhD adviser might get the wrong idea: I don't know any former athletes doing a PhD in my field, but I know at least one professor who thinks being an athlete could be a distraction. Unfortunately, in my country there is not a strong sports culture, and hence the academic and sport worlds are completely disjoint. Do you think I should mention my former career as an athlete in a curriculum for a PhD application?

Comment: «Unfortunately, in my country there is not a strong sports culture, and hence the academic and sport worlds are completely disjoint» Why is that unfortunate? Being evaluated for your academic skills rather than how fast you run seems reasonable and pretty fair to me.

Comment: I was a college athlete (who spent far more time on my sport than on academics) and am now a PhD student in math. I briefly mentioned it in my applications and it didn't seem to hurt me. I've also had many more positive responses to me being a former athlete than negative ones in grad school. This is in the US, by the way. See also this story: http://tech.mit.edu/V135/N38/urschel.html

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I never said that the fact that you "run fast" should overcome your academic skills in your evaluation. But I do think that sports are very important in the growth of a person. Imho, an educational system that discourages doing sport because it distracts from study, is not a good educational system. I know very well the Italian situation: if you want to pursue a sport career in an individual sport, you pretty much have to enroll in the army. Pretty sad in my opinion.

Comment: You are asking a question about (academic) cultural views, but you don't reveal either your country of origin or the countries that you plan to apply to.  IMO, this means that you will have to wonder to what extent every answer you get applies to your situation.  I suggest including more information.

Comment: The dean of Stern School of Mamagement was a wide receiver for UNC, and won the British college basketball championship while spending a year there. It's not math, but I think a lot of people would agree with your reasons for why having been a competitive athlete is a good sign. If you ever go to industry, highlight it definitely.

Comment: @Hamlin: Are you sure you are asking specifically about sports, or about any extra-curricular activity in general?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark You are right, sports are considered in a very different way in US and in Europe. I am going to apply for PhD programs in north Europe, but I want to keep this question general, because I am interested also in opinions from the US.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I am asking specifically about sports done at semi-pro (or higher) level. For that, I mean doing sports and at least being sponsored. Anyone can do sports for fun, and this does not tell anything to a potential supervisor. The situation is different for high level sport.

Comment: @Hamlin: I see. I. that case, I fully agree with AndreaLazzarotto in that I find it very fortunate that one specific extra-curricular activity does not generally have any other bearing on the application than other such activities. If semi-professional sports were considered meaningful in this context, I would feel actively discriminated against and I would also see the risk that such a policy could restrict the diversity among the team.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I didn't say that doing sport should be a discriminating factor. I don't think that. I just think that being a former athlete tells positive things about your attitude to a PhD, just as many other extra curricular activities, and I was looking for opinions about that.

Comment: @Hamlin you said that "unfortunately" those worlds are disjoint and that's what I replied to. You seem to imply that the american model where people can get scholarships just because they are athletes is good, but it isn't.  Doing a sport is good, but it should never influence your academic career, neither in a good nor in a bad way.

Comment: Being a college level athlete is definitely a bonus for you in any endeavor including pursuit of a Ph. D. From my Point of view it seems it can only help your application by showcasing the skills you mentioned in your post. Perhaps you can (in cover letter or informal conversation or email) discuss how your experiences as an athlete helped you improve your ability to perform research.

Comment: @Hamlin How does wanting to play sports entail enrolling into he army?.

Answer (score 16):

I would put it in your CV. I see several reasons for this: first it completes your CV and you are 'honest' with anyone you apply to. I don't know the sports you are in but if someone googles your name, s/he might end up finding you which in my opinion raises questions (if you did not mention it).

The second reason is that of traits and skills a semi-professional career as athlete gives you: persistance, discipline and so on. Yes, it may distract you, but this is why you have chosen to focus on one path. Be prepared to answer questions about this when you are interviewed. Focus on the positive aspects that this occupation has given you.

Third: I think it highly depends on your sport. Is it athletics, football, or something else (popular) it is perhaps ok. Something like Mixed Martial Arts raises other questions and might put you into a unwanted light (agressive, conflict orientated). Sports like e-sports are also still a problem. Many do not recognise them as sports at all, although they might indicate team and communication skills as well as reflexes.

So I guess you should reflect upon the positive and negative aspects of your sport and why it has formed your character into the person you are know. If you can answer questions about this relation in an interview setting, you are pretty well off I think.

Comment: I agree that he should mention it. Impressive accomplishments--like being a semi-pro athlete--show that you have work ethic and drive. But it should be very brief, a line or two in his CV at most, because it's not directly relevant to his field of study.

Comment: Regarding e-sports, see here: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/62496/19607

Comment: I saw this post on poker a few weeks ago. I think it is still something different than esports. Poker still is considered gambling. However, I think we can agree to that esports are a difficult thing.

Answer (score 9):

There are several parts of a typical Ph.D. application.  In some of them, sports will almost certainly not appear; in others I think it will strongly depend on whether *you* find your sports experience highly relevant to your progress as a graduate student.  Here are the places that I think sports might appear:

- In letters of recommendation, your sports will likely not appear at all, since your recommenders are likely recommending you on the basis of your academic work.  Still, you likely have no control here, and if one of your recommenders feels that mentioning sports strengthens your application, they may do so.
- In your personal statement, you should only mention sports if you believe that they are highly relevant to your development and goals for a Ph.D.   For some [they most absolutely are](https://www.media.mit.edu/people/hherr); for others, they are largely separate.
- In your C.V., I see two places that sports might appear:

  1. If your "semi-professional" status as an athlete actually meant you were being paid, then it should probably appear in your list of prior work experience.
  2. Sometimes as C.V. has a miscellaneous "other experience" section at the bottom, in which you might put a bullet point on sports.

In short, there is not much place for sports to appear unless you believe it is critical to your path in academia.  Nor does there need to be a conspicuous absence, however: if you have just that bullet point at the end of your C.V., that signals "this was a big thing in my life, but it's not what I'm focusing on here."

Comment: Your first bullet point suggests that you think that non-academic work experience should appear on an academic CV.  In my circles (mathematics in the US), it usually does not.

Comment: Speaking for Germany and the EU, non-academic work experience is displayed in a seperate vocation list. Especially so if you worked during your academic education or a PhD programme. I think this might actually depend on the subject and the 'culture' of presenting CVs.